# web interface for potentiometer in aws iot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-analytics, aws-iot-events

actually, I write program in Arduino ide which read potentiometer value and send it to AWS MQTT. whenever I revolve my potentiometer it prints value in AWS MQTT and now I want it to access from web page tell me what are the possible ways we access the data on web page
thanks.

I try to access it through node red in AWS cloud formation.my node is complete but it shows connecting error and not connected.

Comment: Could you share your CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways available. I think this blog will be helpful - [7 patterns for IoT data ingestion and visualization- How to decide what works best for your use case](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/7-patterns-for-iot-data-ingestion-and-visualization-how-to-decide-what-works-best-for-your-use-case/)

If you want to directory interact with IoT Core from Web browser, [Amplify PubSub Library](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/pubsub/getting-started/q/platform/js/) may be good.